# Confusion with Libgdx UI

Tags: libgdx, ui-design

I've started with Libgdx and am currently stumbling about trying to understand how to set up the interface.  I have generated the base projects in Eclipse ( < proj-name >,< proj-name >-android, < proj-name >-desktop, < proj-name >-html), and can get the program to display a simple background, play a looping sound file, and draw a tank.  I have been having some problems implementing the UI though.

I want to make a collapsible interface bar at the bottom of the screen that would contain buttons for movement, and selecting weapons.  I'm confused since there appears to be several ways of doing this and the documentation (or tutorials explaining it) tend to be obsolete.  How would one go about this?  Use a stage for the bar and actors for the widgets?  I'm a little lost on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scene2d.ui`. The biggest challenge is finding examples/documentation to match the version you are using.

Some links to get you started:

- https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui
- http://steigert.blogspot.com/2012/03/4-libgdx-tutorial-tablelayout.html

Also be sure to look at the tutorials listed at http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation.html

Comment: Everything's moving to GitHub, now. The better link is https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui

Comment: Another more up to date example is: https://rskupnik.github.io/libgdx-ui-overview